# How do I know under which collection/folder my open tab belongs to?

Tags: postman

This may be a basic question, but I found this as huge obstacle to navigate across Postman requests. I have a ton of collections and each has several requests. On the other hand (right panel), I have a few active tabs open with API calls that I am currently testing. My difficulty here is I am not easily able to locate under which exact collection and its folders my open tab belongs to. This feature may exist somewhere and just that I am not able to find it. What I am looking for is more like *Link with Editor* in *Project Explorer* window in Eclipse, which when clicked highlights and shows me the folder absolute location of my file being edited so that I can easily spot under which folder my currently open window (file) is.
This one thing is bothering me for now by causing difficulty in basic navigation, so any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Postman also highlights the request in the tree :**

[image]

**But when you open postman for the first time it looks hectic as all collections are in collapsed state:**

[image]

**Solution:**

Search for the specific request name:

[image]

This shows under which collection and under what folder the specific request is under .

if you click on collection it will be highlighted, if you click request name that will be highlighted and so on.

Comment: Thanks so much!. Issue is we cannot search if API name same across all folders. Lets say my request "TokenService" which I use to get tokens needed for my subsequent calls. So for each env I have a different folder, like DEV, SIT, and so on and "TokenService" name remains same across all my folders. If I open Postman and see two TokenService windows, I am not sure which one belongs under which folder if I have to change one. Postman should somehow highlight the folder or tell me the path once I select my service window. I do not want to search as I may have same name in other folders.

Comment: When you first open don't click any collection , just search the request name ,even if multiples are there it highlights correctly . If still it's not highlighting click to another tab and click back to the tab you want to highlight

Comment: Really appreciate your guidance. This surely helps me to locate my requests and this is what I am looking for. Although this solves my problem and unblocks me, if any such feature could help to highlight automatically the absolute request path on the navigation window once an open window request is selected instead of going and typing the name to search each time, that would be really nice. Hope Postman team would consider this tiny enhancement that makes users life more easy with such a powerful and elegant tool. Thanks again!!

Comment: You could raise this request in postman app support

Comment: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues